# If style sheet exists then pull in this javascript file

Tags: php

I need a javascript file to pull in if I am using a specific style sheet how exactly can I do this. This needs to be an if-else statement I'm new to coding please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you would like others to look at your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML & CSS only then you can use JavaScript condition for this purpose. & If you are using PHP then you can use PHP Condition too.

**Using JavaScript:**

```
<script>
// Define a variable. Later on this variable will be use to detect whether you add the stylesheet 1 or not.
var stylesheet_1 = false;
var x = document.createElement("LINK");
x.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
x.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
x.setAttribute("href", "style.css");
document.head.appendChild(x);
stylesheet_1 = true;
// Adding JavaScript File only if stylesheet_1 variable is true;
if (stylesheet_1)
{
    var y = document.createElement("script");
    y.setAttribute("src", "script.css");
    document.head.appendChild(y);
}
</script>
```

**Using PHP:**

```
<?php
$stylesheet_1 = false;
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<?php
$stylesheet_1 = true;
?>
<?php
if ($stylesheet_1)
{
    ?>
    <script src="script.css"></script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

** try this **

```
Var_name.style.cssText="//multiple css";
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more in-depth?